# Passing exact date entered by user from Javascript to .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, datetime, nodatime

In our ASP.NET MVC web application for private schools, a user can input dates for calendar events (and other things, i.e. homework due dates) that are meant to be interpreted using the *school's* time zone, which may not necessarily be the same as their own computer (i.e. if they are using the web app while on vacation in another state).

I would like to just pass dates literally, so that when I receive them on the server, I can know exactly what value was entered by the user and let the server take care of converting it to UTC time based on the school's time zone.

On the flip side, I would also like for the server to pass already adjusted dates to the client, and then the client should display those dates as-is. I don't want the dates to be automatically converted to the computer's time zone because I want all dates to be displayed in the school's time zone.

We're using Json.NET for serializing/deserializing JSON. Our current settings for dates are:

```
serializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
serializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

Perhaps I should be using a different option for DateTimeZoneHandling...?

The big problem when deserializing Dates is the actual date the user entered is not preserved, unless they are in the same time zone as our server. So if a client in Pacific enters a date with a time of 4:00 PM, then the server (in Central time) will see it as 6:00 PM, which is correct in that they represent the same time in UTC, but what I really want is to know that the user input 4:00 PM, and take care of figuring out what UTC time that actually represents on the server side.

I'm using NodaTime on the server to handle the conversion of user-input times to an actual UTC time to be stored in the database.

My current solution in javascript, when receiving dates from the server, is to convert them *back* to UTC so that I have the actual date the server passed. This part feels pretty hacky.

```
    function convertToUTCDate(date) {
        var utcDate = new Date(
            date.getUTCFullYear(),
            date.getUTCMonth(),
            date.getUTCDate(),
            date.getUTCHours(),
            date.getUTCMinutes(),
            date.getUTCSeconds()
        );

        return utcDate;
    }
```

I've looked at a lot of StackOverflow questions, and I've gone through Matt Johnson's Date and Time Fundamentals course in PluralSight. I've learned a lot of good principles regarding dates in javascript and .NET, but they all seemed to be different from my case in this: I don't care what the user's time zone is, I want all dates to be displayed in the school's time zone, and also treat date inputs as if they were entering a time in the context of the school's time zone.

Is there an easy and non-hacky way to do what I'm trying to do, in both directions? (client sending dates to server, server sending dates to client)

Comment: Leave all dates as strings, don't use Date objects. You could use Date objects if you use only UTC methods for **everything**, but that might be laborious. Just send strings and write some simple reformatting functions (e.g. to convert 2016-02-24 to 24 February, 2016 is trivial). BTW, you can do the UTC thing by simply adding the timezone offset to the date, so: `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + date.getTimezoneOffset())` will mean the local values will be the same as previous UTC values.

Comment: @RobG - adding the offset minutes how you suggest is essentially doing the same thing as the how he shows passing UTC based fields into the constructor where local time is expected.  Both are fundamentally wrong, as they just *shift* the moment in time being represented, without actually changing the time zone.  (But I do agree that a string-based solution might be appropriate on the client-side for this scenario.)

Comment: Ok, leaving dates as strings seems like a good solution for displaying values received from the server. But since I need to also be able to edit those dates, is that still a feasible solution? Seems like it would be better to be dealing with an actual Date object in that case. FYI, I'm using a KendoUI DateTimePicker along with KnockoutJS to track an observable Date value right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the scenario you described, it sounds like the easiest thing to do is to just pass unqualified date and time values, rather than local or UTC.

- On the server, use `DateTime` values with `Unspecified` kind, or use Noda Time's `LocalDateTime`.
- Leave JSON.Net's date format handling at the defaults, which are `DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat` and `DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind`.  You rarely need to modify these, as long as you pay attention to `Kind` properly.

  - If you're serializing Noda Time types directly, then be sure to wire up the NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet library using `ConfigureForNodaTime`, as described [in the user guide](http://nodatime.org/userguide/serialization.html).
- Over the wire, the data should look like `"eventTime" : "2016-03-01T10:00:00"`.  Don't include a `Z`, as you're not sending UTC.  Don't include an offset either.
- On the client side, don't use the `Date` object.  It is always going to be working in the local time zone.  Instead, consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

  - There's no "unspecified" mode in moment, but you can fake it by using  UTC mode, even though the value isn't actually in UTC, this will still work well for formatting.  Call `moment.utc(yourvalue)`.  Don't use `moment(yourvalue)`, because it will then be in *local* mode, and will take on the DST behavior of the local time zone just like the `Date` object.
  - Alternatively, you really *can* just use strings as RobG suggested in comments.  You just have to parse and format them between user input and wire-format yourself.  Some may find that easy, others prefer to let a library do it.

Lastly, recognize that I'm making this recommendation based on a lot of assumptions from the scenario you described.  It may or may not be ideal, if there are additional use cases you didn't explain.  For example, if you're sending the same values to some third-party over this API, then a `DateTimeOffset`, serialized with the offset included, might be more appropriate.

Also recognize that you *could* do this all client-side, using something like moment-timezone.  However that's probably not necessary for this particular case.

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed answer Matt! All the other detailed answers you give regarding DateTime issues on StackOverflow and your Date and Time Fundamentals course have been a huge help to me! I'll take a stab at your suggestions tomorrow morning. I think dropping the Z and the offset from the data on the wire might have been the big piece I was missing.

Comment: Hope it helps.  Hard to give *exact* advice without seeing your code, of course.  But I think I get what you're going for.

Comment: It seems like my problem would be a more common scenario in web applications - i.e. a user is entering data for their organization or business while currently located in a different time zone, so all dates should be represented in the organization's time zone and not their own. In your experience, is that very common? I'm wondering if it might be better for me to not worry about the cases where users are in a different time zone from their school, and leave it up to them to do the conversions to the school's time in their head.

Comment: Yes, it's a common case, but not the default one that JavaScript sets you up for.  I think you are on the right track though.  Consider that if you were just rendering all data on the server, such as in an MVC view, or WebForms aspx page, that you'd still be sending data in a similar form - it's just that it would be preformatted for display, rather than in ISO8601.  It's the JSON API layer that makes the difference.

Comment: Here's a different approach you could explore - in your JSON, send a DateTimeOffset, where the value is ISO8601 format in the school's time zone with the school's offset.  Then you have to to parse and reformat it with something like `moment.parseZone(value).format('LLLL')` (or whatever format you want).   Alternatively, you could do it all server sider, sending *two* fields.  One is the ISO8601 UTC or DateTimeOffset, and the other is pre-formatted display string, already converted to the school's time zone and the user's prefered date format.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I was baffled watching your course yesterday by how many things JavaScript does wrong with dates.

Comment: None of these approaches are invalid - it's just about what works better in your particular set of use cases.   Glad you like the course.  In addition to module 7 on JavaScript, see module 9,  section 3 "Understanding Time Zones", towards the end, the part I labeled "You Can't Fool JavaScript".  That's relevant here.

Comment: Ok, I'll go back and watch that part! I'll be trying out these ideas today to see what works well. Thank you for the extra ideas for approaches, it will be really nice to have several options to work with! Due to development time crunches my main criteria is probably going to be which one causes the least amount of refactoring to existing code. (unfortunately)

Comment: I got it working! I'm representing all dates as strings in my Knockout viewmodels, in the `2016-03-01T10:00:00` format. Whenever I need to display them, I create a moment object from the string, and then format it. Unfortunately, for editing dates, I convert the strings to javascript Date objects, because we are using KendoUI for our datepicker, which doesn't seem to be compatible with moment.js. The Date is converted back to a string as soon as they select a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I get what you are saying.

But if you use something like momentjs, then don't convert to the timezone on the server.  Just use UTC dates everywhere, then tell the client javascript what the timezone to use is, then use moment to convert the utc time to the timezone you want to display.